# How can I set "Login" as text for anonymous and "Logout" for authenticated users in twig and symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a menu that all items appear for all users and I want to hide/show specific items to specific ROLE users in symfony2.

For example, I have

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">{{ 'menu.home'|trans }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('guest') }}">{{ 'menu.articles'|trans }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('category') }}">{{ 'menu.categories'|trans }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('user') }}">{{ 'menu.users'|trans }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('logout') }}">{{ 'menu.logout'|trans }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now Logout appears to all users, even If they are not logged in. How can I make twig check whether a user is authenticated or not and then choose

`<li><a href="{{ path('login') }}">{{ 'menu.login'|trans }}</a></li>` ?

Comment: I know about {% if app.user %} but this does not check ROLES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Twig` do following check:

```
{% if app.user %}
    <li><a href="{{ path('logout') }}">{{ 'menu.logout'|trans }}</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a href="{{ path('login') }}">{{ 'menu.login'|trans }}</a></li> 
{% endif %}
```

In case if you have different roles and you'd like to render some parts of the page dependent on user role, you can do next check:

```
{% if is_granted('YOUR_ROLE') %} ... {% endif %}
```