# Symfony2 Project, Problems with template design using twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, templates, twig

I have a doubt about templates using twig, my problem is the following, I have a page called index.html.twig, which extends from base.html.twig.
In index.html.twig there are two include blocks, (one is for the upper menu bar; a navbar and the other one corresponds to the footer)
My navbar contains the following options for anonymous users,

--Login--Register--Contact--

Now, if I sign in, I wanted to load a different navbar instead of the previous one, for example

--You're signed as Blablabla-- Edit profile -- Exit --

How can I accomplish this? I mean, to include different blocks based on a session.
Do I have to check in the view if the user is logged in?
Or do I have to check in the controller if the user has session and then load a different index.html.twig(one for logged in users.)
In relation with the last option, I can create an index.html.twig, and an indexLoggedIn.html.twig, and in the controller I can check, if the user is logged in I render indexLoggedIn, otherwise I load index.html.twig.
I used the FOSUserBundle for user management. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
{% if app.user and is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
  {{ include('FooBarBundle:Navbar:authenticated.html.twig') }}
{% else %}
  {{ include('FooBarBundle:Navbar:anonymous.html.twig') }}
{% endif %}
```

See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-in-a-template) about when to check for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` and when to use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`. And see [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660881/3492835) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7470163/3492835) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810893/3492835) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17638467/3492835) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524289/3492835) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992232/3492835) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11925241/3492835) for more hints.